# Firebase Messaging - Maximum frequency of subscription

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

The Firebase Messaging documentation states

> The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.

The scenario I have to handle goes like this

- I have Android and iOS apps that could typically have several 100s to a few thousand active users at any given time
- Each user subscribes to multiple topics.  The topic names are auto generated by the app based on user location and other user behavior
- I limit re-subscription to topics internally - at present resubscription cannot happen any more frequently than once every 3 minutes

In light of what I have quoted above my concern is this - if, say, each user device is subscribing to 10 topics and then periodically switching out (unsubscribing) a subset of those topics and replacing them with a few others at what threshold of subscription rate am I likely to get the 429 message?

For instance, will my pool of users generating, say, 50 subscriptions/minute be deemed as being excessive and requiring a backoff?